# how to replace word lookAt:=xlWhole including japanese comma in excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

have to replace the word in excel cell .
using like

```
Sub test()
Dim a_row As String
Dim b_row As String
Dim row_counter As Integer
For row_counter = 1 To 600
    a_row = "A" & row_counter
    b_row = "B" & row_counter
    Dim Findtext As String
    Dim Replacetext As String
    Findtext = Sheets("sheet1").Range(a_row).Value
    Replacetext = Sheets("sheet1").Range(b_row).Value
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name Then
            ws.Cells.Replace What:=Findtext, Replacement:=Replacetext, LookAt:= _
            xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False,    SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        End If
    Next ws

Next row_counter
End Sub
```

there are two cols in sheet1. 1st cols shows Japanese words. 2nd column shows English words.

```
公園  park
夏   summer    
緑   Green
青空  blue Sky
男の人 man
```

In the 2nd sheet displays in col A

```
    column A
公園、夏、青空、緑、男の人
```

the above code replace Japanese words.

if LookAt:= _xlPart, after replace shows like below

park, summer, 青sky, green,manの人

if LookAt:= _xlWhole , its not replacing the word

In the 2nd sheet displays in the separate columns

```
 A    B    C     D     E
公園  夏  青空    緑    男の人
```

if LookAt:= _xlWhole then

its working perfectly.

i want to do

In the 2nd sheet displays the value in single col A delimited by comma

```
column A
公園、夏、青空、緑、男の人
```

need the output like
park, summer, blue sky, green,man

please give some idea.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in memory instead, it's quicker and much easier to work with arrays. If I understand the way your data is set out - the following should work where your find/replace table is in columns A:B on sheet1 and the values to replace are in sheet2 and are comma separated in cell A1:

```
Sub MM_Foo()

Dim findArray       As Variant
Dim replaceArray    As Variant
Dim matchPosition   As Long

With Sheets(1)
    findArray = .Range("A1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

On Error GoTo checkErr:

For j = 1 To Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    replaceArray = Split(Sheets(2).Cells(j, 1).Value, ",")

    With Application
        For i = LBound(replaceArray) To UBound(replaceArray)

            matchPosition = .Match(replaceArray(i), .Index(findArray, , 1), 0)
            replaceArray(i) = findArray(matchPosition, 2)

skipReplace:

        Next
    End With

    Sheets(2).Cells(j, 1).Value = Join$(replaceArray, ",")

Next

On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub

checkErr:
    If Err.Number = 13 Then
        Err.Clear
        GoTo skipReplace:
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Description & " (" & Err.Number & ")", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice approach. Error control on the match ?

Comment: @Jeeped you mean `On Error Resume Next`? _(Joking! I've updated code)_

Comment: @VJS Didn't realise you had multiple rows - updated to loop through rows

Answer (score 2):

Without a trailing 'comma', there may have to be repetitive passes that may or may not actually do anything; there need to cover all possible combinations.

```
Sub delimitedTranslate()
    Dim w As Long, vWRDs As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        vWRDs = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), _
                       .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)) _
                       .Value2
    End With
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        With .Columns("A")
            For w = LBound(vWRDs, 1) To UBound(vWRDs, 1)
                .Replace what:=vWRDs(w, 1) & ChrW(12289), _
                         replacement:=vWRDs(w, 2) & Chr(44), _
                         lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False
                .Replace what:=ChrW(12289) & vWRDs(w, 1), _
                         replacement:=Chr(44) & vWRDs(w, 2), _
                         lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False
                .Replace what:=Chr(44) & vWRDs(w, 1), _
                         replacement:=Chr(44) & vWRDs(w, 2), _
                         lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False
            Next w
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: translate_Sheet1]   [image: translate_Sheet2_before]   [image: translate_Sheet2_after]
           <sup>Sheet1 terms</sup>                  <sup>Sheet2 before delimitedTranslate</sup>                 <sup>Sheet2 after delimitedTranslate</sup>